# 2D animating a simple image with simple movement

Tags: image, 2d

Blender version: 2.82

I am fairly new to Blender. My goal is to 2D animate an image going from the left to the right and scaling the image while it's moving.

So far I have tried:

- Clicking on the desired frame time and dragging the image, then clicking on "Insert keyframe"
- Going to object mode and clicking on "Add image" and attempted to add it to grease pencil by converting the object to a mesh which failed.
- Trying out other modes other than grease pencil but none of them could add an image (nor could grease pencil)

Comment: You can follow @Christopher's answer on an image Shift A  > Image > Images as Planes. Check the shading options, etc,  in the file browser when you select the image to import.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple animation, start with the object in it's "starting position" with the timeline at 0. Press N to bring up the transform tools window, and press <kbd>I</kbd> over both the location and scale boxes to insert a keyframe (one press of <kbd>I</kbd> works for all three axis boxes).

[image: KeyFrame1]

Then, move your timeline forward, move and scale the object accordingly, and then again, press <kbd>I</kbd> over the rotation and scale, to set a new keyframe at the new time position with the new transforms applied. You should now be able to play your animation and watch the object move and scale accordingly.

[image: KeyFrame2]